# What is the English translation of the German "Grundbereich" and/or "Träger"?

Tags: logic, terminology, translation-request, mathematical-german

In German, "Grundbereich" and "Träger" stand for the set over which a structure is defined. For example, for the structure $G=(\mathbb{R},\cdot,1)$ the "Grundbereich" or "Träger" is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Do you have a source for that? I'm German and never heard of "Grundbereich". I would translate "Träger" with "support", but then again I don't really understand your example.

Comment: Source: "Einführung in die mathematische Logik", by H.-D. Ebbinghaus, J. Flum, and W. Thomas.

Comment: Maybe "the underlying set"?

Comment: @PhoemueX: Reading this ->https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Underlying_Set I think that you are right. Thank you!

Comment: It’s the *domain* or *underlying set* of a model; it’s also sometimes called the *universe* of the model.

Comment: "Bereich" can usually be translated as "domain" -- domain of a function, a principal ideal domain is a "Hauptidealbereich", and so on... The key is identifying in what sense domain is meant given the context. I can also confirm that Träger usually means "support" in other contexts, for example "Funktionen mit kompaktem Träger" is functions with compact support.

Comment: Little remark, since you are reading a book by W. Thomas: In his lectures he usually used "domain" as the English translation.

Answer (score 3):

*This question was answered in the comments; I'm answering it here to move it off the unanswered list. I've made this answer community wiki so I don't receive reputation for it. If one of the original commenters posts an answer, I'll delete this one.*

This is the "underlying set" of the structure - also called the "domain," the "universe," the "carrier set," the "support" (although I've only seen that one used once or twice), and probably a few other things given how obnoxious logic sometimes is about terminology.

(I personally favor "underlying set" since it emphasizes the possibility of other underlying things - e.g. the underlying group of a ring - but "domain" and "universe" are in my experience equally common.)